# how to extract item and product ids in given url string in r

Tags: r

How to extract item id and product id from given url string in r
http://www.exploratorystore.io/cart.do?action=addtocart&itemId=EST-12&categoryId=STRATEGY&productId=DC-SG-G02

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing URLs is something which most enterprise languages already have special libraries to handle, and R is no different.  R has a [`urltools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urltools/urltools.pdf) library which can help here:

```
url <- "http://www.exploratorystore.io/cart.do?action=addtocart&itemId=EST-12&categoryId=STRATEGY&productId=DC-SG-G02"
parameter_values <- param_get(url, c("itemId", "productId"))
```

If, for some reason, you can't use a library here, you *could* split the URL yourself and extract out the parameters.  But you should never opt for doing unnecessary work unless there is a good reason to do so.

Comment: Ok its good.THanks! Now i want to store these ids in dataframe of colnames item and product....how to achieve this using dplyr..

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` option would be to extract with `regmatches/gregexpr`

```
regmatches(str1, gregexpr("(?<=itemId\\=)[^&]*|(?<=productId\\=)[^&]*",
           str1, perl = TRUE))[[1]]
#[1] "EST-12"    "DC-SG-G02"
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- "http://www.exploratorystore.io/cart.do?action=addtocart&itemId=EST-12&categoryId=STRATEGY&productId=DC-SG-G02"
```